# Détails sur le sens « favorable » de la locution adjectivale « vent debout » ?

Tags: prépositions, adjectifs, locutions, fréquence-utilisation

On a la locution adjectivale « [vent debout](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vent_debout#Locution_adjectivale) » signifiant « farouchement opposé » (...contre) mais aussi rarement « farouchement favorable » (...pour).

- Comment se fait-il qu'une locution qui s'appuie sur l'idée du vent
  opposé puisse aussi signifier « favorable » ; est-ce que ce sens est
  attesté dès le début de l'emploi de la locution ?
- Est-ce courant de retrouver ce phénomène avec de telles locutions ?
- Peut-on qualifier la « rareté » de la fréquence de l'emploi favorable
  ?
- La locution prépositive « [vent debout contre](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vent_debout_contre) » ne permet-elle
  pas aussi ce sens favorable ?

Comment: le sens favorable dans le premier lien me semble résulter d'une double négation, e.g. `les élus sont vent debout contre la fermeture de l'hôpital`  et "contre la fermeture" => sauver.

Comment: +1, Je n'emploierais pas "vent debout" hors du contexte d'une lutte contre une adversité. Il peut s'agir d'une lutte *contre* ou d'une lutte *pour que l'inverse d'une chose n'arrive pas*. On n'est jamais "vent debout" simplement pour approuver quelque chose d'agréable ou de bénéfique, sans une force contraire.

Comment: @Archemar On peut trouver des [exemples](https://www.profession-audiovisuel.com/les-compositeurs-vent-debout-pour-defendre-la-musique-a-limage/) où il n'y cette double négation sous-jacente...

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle le chapo de l'article donne pourtant le ton : *La musique à l’image fait face à de nombreux défis*. Plus loin, on parle de "grandes problématiques". Il s'agit bien de "défendre" la musique contre quelque chose.

Answer (score 1):

Selon moi, "*vent debout* ***contre***" appelle naturellement son inverse "*vent debout* ***pour***". Si on connaît pas bien l'expression, on peut imaginer que ça veut simplement dire "*fortement militant (pour/contre quelque chose)*".

Comment: Donc tu sembles dire que le sens de _vent de bout_ s'estompe au profit d'une idée comme _se tenir debout_ ?

Answer (score 1):

L'expression *vent debout* aurait pu continuer s'écrire *vent de bout* (comme *vent de face*) puisqu'à l'origine, c'est de la proue, le « bout » du navire qui fait face au vent dont il s'agit (*avoir le vent de bout*), pas d'une personne debout.

La première apparition attestée de ***être** vent debout contre*, au sens figuré, date de 1986. On y perçoit l'allégorie d'un marin debout face au vent.

> *Les organismes HLM [...] se dressèrent vent debout contre ce qu'ils ressentaient comme la révolution, la fin d'un monopole !* Albin Chalandon

*Vent debout pour*, plus récent et encore bien rare, est une suite logique qui fait l'objet de cette remarque de Marc81 sur son blog :

> Curieusement, quelques emplois de (*être*) *vent debout pour* font leur apparition au sens de « (être) farouchement favorable à » : « Des officiers supérieurs vent debout pour défendre leurs collègues de l'état-major » (Serge July). Preuve, s'il en était besoin, de la confusion de sens entre debout (dans son acception nautique) et debout (dans son acception figurée « en  gardant une attitude digne et fière »).

Source: [Parler français](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/un-coup-du-vent-a120982774)